# Why merge() doesn't work on matrix with character components?

Tags: r

I have twom matrix, and I want to merge both matrix based on one their columns called "IDs".

Here is the structure of my matrices :

```
> M[1:4,]
     IDs        Ref_IDs    
[1,] "uc021vdf" "NR_034035"
[2,] "uc021vdg" "NR_034035"
[3,] "uc002qvr" "NR_034035"
[4,] "uc021vdh" "NR_034035"
> 


> F<-as.matrix(P, ncol=1)
> dim(F)
[1] 73598     1
> colnames(F)<-c("IDs")
> F[1:4,]
[1] "uc010unu" "uc010uoa" "uc002bgz" "uc002bic"
```

and I'm trying to merge them based on column called "IDs"

Here is my effort:

```
 C <- merge(M, F, by.x = 0, by.y = "IDs" )
```

But, I got nothing and I'm sure that, most of the elements of the column called "IDs" are same in two matrices.

```
> C
[1] Row.names IDs       Ref_IDs  
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Would someone help me to solve this problem ?

Comment: what are you trying to do with `by.x = 0`?

Comment: I think , it's says that, does not merge the rows, merge the columns

Comment: No, according to the help file 0 means to merge by the row names.

Comment: Just do `C <- merge(M, F, by = "IDs" )`. You'll need to decide what type of join it will be, outer (`, all = T`) inner, left (`, all.x = T`) or right (`all.y = T`)

Comment: Ok, after braking my head on this, the reason you can't merge this is because, well, there is no a single incident in `M[,1]` that matches `F[,1]`!!!

Comment: My guess is that merge is being asked for out of ignorance and that an effect like `plyr::rbind.fill` is what is desired. People should explain what they want in natural language rather than with failing code.